# Watching a directory with nodejs - Not registering files uploaded by ftp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ftp, fs

I'm trying to watch for any newly added files to an ftp server, which has the directory mapped to a drive on the server that's running the node application. The problem is that it doesn't register any events for files added through ftp; when files are modified or created through the node application they are picked up fine.

I'm currently using chokidar to watch the directory and log any events with the simple code below:

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch('./myDir', {
persistent: true,
awaitWriteFinish: {
  stabilityThreshold: 2000,
  pollInterval: 100
}
});

watcher
.on('add', path => console.log(`File ${path} has been added`))
.on('change', path => console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`));
```

I've added the `awaitWriteFinish` option to try to see if it will register when the file is completed from the ftp transfer, but with no joy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to do that with the native API? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: Yes, with the same result. I had read that chokadir was more reliable at registering events that fs.watch missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch a directory using the native module [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const folderPath = './test';
const pollInterval = 300;

let folderItems = {};
setInterval(() => {
  fs.readdirSync(folderPath)
  .forEach((file) => {
    let path = `${folderPath}/${file}`;
    let lastModification = fs.statSync(path).mtimeMs;
    if (!folderItems[file]) {
      folderItems[file] = lastModification;
      console.log(`File ${path} has been added`);
    } else if (folderItems[file] !== lastModification) {
      folderItems[file] = lastModification;
      console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`);
    }
  });
}, pollInterval);
```

But the above example will not watch the files in subfolders. Another approach to watch all subfolders, is to use unix `find` through the node [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) function.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
const folderPath = './test';
const pollInterval = 500;

let folderItems = {};
setInterval(() => {
  let fileList = execSync(`find ${folderPath}`).toString().split('\n');
  for (let file of fileList) {
    if (file.length < 1) continue;
    let lastModification = fs.statSync(file).mtimeMs;
    if (!folderItems[file]) {
      folderItems[file] = lastModification;
      console.log(`File ${file} has been added`);
    } else if (folderItems[file] !== lastModification) {
      folderItems[file] = lastModification;
      console.log(`File ${file} has been changed`);
    }
  }
}, pollInterval);
```

Comment: This is a good solution if the files are directly within the /test directory. However, I need to check for files within /test/xx/xx.

Comment: Added an example using unix `fiind`  to watch all subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Use `usePolling: true` on `watcher-chokidar`